# NReco.PdfGenerator in ASP.NET stopped working on server

Tags: asp.net, exception, iis

Local PDF generation works well, but the same application stoped working on server. Event log says:

> Faulting application wkhtmltopdf.exe, version 0.12.2.1, time stamp 0x54bd0265, faulting module MSVCP120.dll, version 6.0.6002.18881, time stamp 0x51da3e00, exception code 0xc0000135, fault offset 0x0006f52f, process id 0x44b8, application start time 0x01d07ce4c087128f.

and

> Exception information: 
>       Exception type: IOException 
>       Exception message: The pipe has been ended.
>
> at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String
>   maybeFullPath)
>   at System.IO.FileStream.WriteCore(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
>   at NReco.PdfGenerator.HtmlToPdfConverter.GeneratePdfInternal(String htmlFilePath, Byte[] inputBytes, String coverHtml, String outputPdfFilePath, Stream outputStream)

Answer (score 1):

I've spent 4 hours wrestling with this today, so I thought i'd post my solution to help anyone else suffering in thr future.

wkhtmltopdf was updated and worked on my local machine.
Pushed the code to the server and nothing.

I eventually tracked this down to needing to install the 32 bit version of C++Runtime from here https://www.microsoft.com/en-GB/download/details.aspx?id=40784

In my case, due to some 3rd party libraries I cannot remove yet, I was forced to run the website in 32 bit mode. As my server is 64 bit, the 32 bit versions were not present. (As my PC is a Dev Machine, I assume that I got all the relevent libraries from MS, hence why I had no local issue.)

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to check accesibility of dll's msvcp120.dll and msvcr120.dll. Local copy of libraries into app bin dir solve my problem.