# NReco.PdfGenerator 1.1.7 does not work in hosted environment

Tags: c++, model-view-controller, wkhtmltopdf

I have invested some hours in creating a set of reports to be generated by PdfCreator. I liked the idea to define the content in HTML and then generate it into PDF files that can be used in both WPF client and MVC site.

It works excellent locally. But when publishing the website to hosted environment the PDF generation suddenly crashes ... Why!!?

The error output on the webpage is not very helpful:

```
(exit code: -1073741701)

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: NReco.PdfGenerator.WkHtmlToPdfException: (exit code: -1073741701)

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[WkHtmlToPdfException:  (exit code: -1073741701)]
   NReco.PdfGenerator.HtmlToPdfConverter.CheckExitCode(Int32 exitCode, String lastErrLine, String outputFilePath) +123
   NReco.PdfGenerator.HtmlToPdfConverter.GeneratePdfInternal(String[] htmlFiles, Byte[] inputBytes, String coverHtml, String outputPdfFilePath, Stream outputStream) +2481

[Exception: Cannot generate PDF:  (exit code: -1073741701)]
   NReco.PdfGenerator.HtmlToPdfConverter.GeneratePdfInternal(String[] htmlFiles, Byte[] inputBytes, String coverHtml, String outputPdfFilePath, Stream outputStream) +2819
   NReco.PdfGenerator.HtmlToPdfConverter.GeneratePdf(String htmlContent, String coverHtml, Stream output) +87
   NReco.PdfGenerator.HtmlToPdfConverter.GeneratePdf(String htmlContent, String coverHtml) +42
   SongService.Report.DomainServices.ReportCompiler.GeneratePdf(String templateName, T model) +704
   SongServiceWeb.Controllers.PresentationController.GetReport(Guid presentationId) +261
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +122
   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +156
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +32
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +225
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass33.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() +26
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +54
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +54
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +21
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +54
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +31
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9651796
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

This question had an interesting suggestion: [NReco.PdfGenerator in ASP.NET stoped working on server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29795885/nreco-pdfgenerator-in-asp-net-stoped-working-on-server)

In the version history of NReco.PdfGenerator it says that 1.1.6 had a new deployment that is dependant upon C++ package.

Quote from Nuget: 
v.1.1.6 changes: WkHtmlToPdf tool upgraded to version 0.12.2.1 (released January 19, 2015). NOTE: this version of wkhtmltopdf requires Visual C++ Redistributable package for VS 2013 (x86). WkHtmlToPdf tool upgraded to version 0.12.2.1 (released January 19, 2015). NOTE: this version of wkhtmltopdf requires Visual C++ Redistributable package for VS 2013 (x86).

Even if my error was different I tried to add the missing files. I included msvcp120.dll and msvcr120.dll but it made no difference. Just to be sure I added vccorlib120.dll and wkhtmltopdf.exe as well. Still no difference.

My next idea was that I needed to point out a temporary directory with write permission, that could be used during internal work. But I don't find any reference to that in the documentation.

EDIT:

I found a property on HtmlToPdfConverter named TempFilesPath. That looked really promising! So I quickly created a directory and set needed write permission.

```
converter.TempFilesPath = HttpContext.Server.MapPath(@"~/_temp");
```

I verified that this directory is readable and writable from code on host. But the error from PdfCreator is still the same ...

Answer (score 0):

Regarding system requirements I found a passage on this page http://www.nrecosite.com/pdf_generator_net.aspx saying:

- PdfGenerator works fine with Azure Web Role / Worker Role / usual VM.
- Azure Web Sites is NOT supported because of GDI WinAPI limitations that prevent WkHtmlToPdf from working.

I guess this might apply to my situation as well. I am not running in Azure, but still in a "cloud service" environment, so it is likely they have the same limitations of GDI WinAPI.

This is really sad. The idea was excellent: Same reports in web and client. But in this setting it didn't work.

Comment: Just an update, the linked page no longer says that. I hope that means they fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

We had similar error saying:Cannot generate PDF: (exit code: -1073741819)

I am putting our solution here if anyone needs. Execute wkhtmltopdf.exe from console and check the error. In our case it was saying some dll's are missing like api-ms-win-core-localization-l1-2-0.dll, api-ms-win-core-timezone-l1-2-0.dll and so on. I dont know why these dll's were not on server. According to operating system, we found correct places under system32 or sysWOW64 folders and copy these dlls to these folders and problem has solved.

For example how to fix api-ms-win-core-timezone-l1-2-0.dll problem, below link will help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s5N0jmYyy34

Comment: I guess this assumes you are responsible for your own server. In a hosted environment you are probably not allowed to add files to the system folders ...